# Phonegap Developer App stuck on Downloading

Tags: ios, phonegap-desktop-app

I have just installed Phonegap Desktop and Phonegap Developer App on my iPhone 5 but when I enter the server ip address that is shown at the bottom of Phonegap Desktop into Phonegap Developer App it gets stuck on the 'DOWNLOADING...' message.

I have tried restarting and rebooting etc. but can't get past the downloading message.

Anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It might be your firewall